# Entity Framework throws exception: index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've been struggling with having a foreign key to' AspNetUsers' table a lot.

I renamed the table to `Users` in my SQL Server database just to clarify. I have a foreign key in my `Tutorial` table to the `Users` table. Here's my EF model class for `Tutorial` table:

```
public class Tutorial
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TutorialID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TutorialTitle { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string TutorialUrl { get; set; }

    public string TutorialContent { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual AppUser User { get; set; } // this on is IdentityUser actually

    public DateTime? Published { get; set; }
    public bool HasBeenAcceptedForPublish { get; set; }
    public string AdminMessageForNotPublishing { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual TutorialStatus TutorialStatus { get; set; }
}
```

So after I updated database, when every I save new `Tutorial` to EF, it throws an error:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

I'm guessing that there is something wrong with foreign key to the `Users` table. It's the `AppUser` object that is related to. I'm gonna throw here script for `Tutorial` table if anyone could make sense, what is throwing that exception/error.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tutorials] 
(
    [TutorialID] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TutorialTitle] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [TutorialUrl] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [TutorialContent] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Published] DATETIME NULL,
    [HasBeenAcceptedForPublish] BIT NOT NULL,
    [AdminMessageForNotPublishing] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [TutorialStatus_TutorialStatusID] INT NOT NULL,
    [UserId] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Tutorials] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TutorialID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Tutorials_dbo.TutorialStatus_TutorialStatusID] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([TutorialStatus_TutorialStatusID]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[TutorialStatus] ([TutorialStatusID]) 
       ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Tutorials_dbo.Users_Id] 
       FOREIGN KEY ([UserId]) 
       REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_TutorialStatus_TutorialStatusID]
ON [dbo].[Tutorials]([TutorialStatus_TutorialStatusID] ASC);
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_UserId]
ON [dbo].[Tutorials]([UserId] ASC);
```

UPDATE:

Here is the code which creates the new tutorial and tries to save it to database.

```
public Tutorial CreateNewTutorial(string TutorialTitle, string Description, string content, AppUser user, out bool success)
{
    try
    {
        string tutorialurl = null;
        tutorialurl = TutorialTitle.Replace(" ", "-");
        Tutorial tutorial = new Tutorial();

        TutorialStatus status = new TutorialStatus();
        status.ViewCount = 1;
        status.ReputationPoints = 0;
        status.FavouritedCount = 0;

        context.TutorialStatus.Add(status);
        context.SaveChanges();

        tutorial.TutorialTitle = TutorialTitle;
        tutorial.Description = Description;
        tutorial.TutorialUrl = tutorialurl;
        tutorial.User = user;
        tutorial.UserId = user.Id;
        tutorial.Published = null;
        //tutorial.TutorialStatusID = status.TutorialStatusID;
        tutorial.TutorialContent = content;

        context.Tutorials.Add(tutorial);
        context.SaveChanges();

        success = true;
        return tutorial;
    }
    catch
    {
        success = false;
        return null;
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2:
Here's the stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.FindRelationshipSet(ObjectContext context, EntitySet entitySet, EdmType& relationshipType, RelationshipSet& relationshipSet)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AttachContext(ObjectContext context, EntitySet entitySet, MergeOption mergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AttachContext(ObjectContext context, MergeOption mergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.CreateRelatedEnd[TSourceEntity,TTargetEntity](RelationshipNavigation navigation, RelationshipMultiplicity sourceRoleMultiplicity, RelationshipMultiplicity targetRoleMultiplicity, RelatedEnd existingRelatedEnd)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipFixer`2.System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.IRelationshipFixer.CreateSourceEnd(RelationshipNavigation navigation, RelationshipManager relationshipManager)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.GetRelatedEnd(RelationshipNavigation navigation, IRelationshipFixer relationshipFixer)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AddObject(String entitySetName, Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassd.<Add>b__c()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
at TutorialNetworkDomain.EFRepositories.EFHomeRepository.CreateNewTutorial(String TutorialTitle, String Description, String content, AppUser user, Boolean& success) in C:\\Users\\Jon\\Source\\Workspaces\\TutorialNetwork\\TutorialNetwork\\TutorialNetworkDomain\\EFRepositories\\EFHomeRepository.cs:line 362
```

Comment: Show the code, which posts new entity and saves changes. Also, could be there a multi-threaded access to the context instance? Do you share the same context between threads?

Comment: I have two different contexts, because they are in two different projects. One handle website logic and one for User management. I'll update my post.

Comment: Where `context` is instantiated?

Comment: Also StackTrace may help a lot...

Comment: Context is instantiated in Controller's constructor

Comment: It's just code that looks like it should work, but the content of some crucial variables isn't visible (like `user`) and it's not clear what this `status` is doing. Also, the EF version isn't given, but important.

Answer (score -1):

Remove this Line `tutorial.User = user;`

Comment: A little explanation wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score -1):

As @behzad told, Remove Line **tutorial.User = user** because it is trying to store an object that is not valid due to which it is throwing an error of index out of bound.

Comment: Based on... what? We don't see the content of this `user` object. Just as the answer you refer to this is a longshot.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35396864)

Comment: Because it's trying to store user that may contain foreign key issues as the user mentioned. If after removing it stores other data successfully then we can look into user obj and its table keys.